# Creating React Native App on Windows 8 without iPhone

Tags: windows-8, reactjs, react-native

I found Exponent, but it requires an iPhone. Can I do complete React native development on Windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You need XCode and Mac to build a react-native project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned is not possible, but you can play, try to do some prototypes, and have fun with https://rnplay.org/

Answer (score 0):

Android Development in React Native at Windows Platform is possible. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html